# How to make a cicrle around radius using latitude and longitude in MAPBOX

Tags: android, mapbox

I am using `Geofence` in `MapBox`, so I want to make a circle for destination based on radius and latitude and longitude in `MapBox`.Please kindly help me.
For `GoogleMap` the code will be like this:

```
Circle circle = googleMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
                .center(new LatLng(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude))
                .radius(Constants.GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS)
                .strokeColor(Color.RED)
                .strokeWidth(4f));
```

For `MapBox` I need code like this or how to customize the circle.Please help me

Comment: Feature request in https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/4312

Comment: am using map box not map box-gl.It's not supported in map box